# Alert Dialogue is not showing on popup item click. Any solution?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dialog

Here is my PopupMenuButton

```
                        PopupMenuButton(
                            icon:
                                Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
                            itemBuilder: (context) => [
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      showMyDialog();
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Edit Profile Picture",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.pinkColor),
                                    ),
                                    value: 1,
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                   
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Edit  Cover Picture",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.pinkColor),
                                    ),
                                    value: 2,
                                  ),
                                  PopupMenuItem(
                                  
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Setting",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.pinkColor),
                                    ),
                                    value: 3,
                                  )
                                ])
```

And this is my Dilaogue function

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Approve'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your method declaration says `_showMyDialog()` and your call says `showMyDialog()` without `_`. Try to call it as you declared the function.

Answer (score 1):

`onTap` of `PopupMenuItem` call `Navigator.pop` after tapping on any item on `PopupMenuButton` to close it.

```dart
 void handleTap() {
    widget.onTap?.call();

    Navigator.pop<T>(context, widget.value);
  }
```

When you tap the item it shows `_showMyDialog()`  but close it immediately because of `Navigator.pop` called and that's why you can find `PopupMenuItem` is open after tap.

Simply `Navigator.pop` is closing the `showDialog` instead of `PopupMenuButton`'s items. We can provide some delay to close the `PopupMenuItem`  then can call `_showMyDialog();`

```dart
PopupMenuItem(
  onTap: () {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
      _showMyDialog();
    });
  },
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: feel free to accept as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that if you've declared function as `_showMyDialogue()`, then you should use `_showMyDialogue()` when calling that function. In your case, you Ignored "_" while calling it. That's the problem.

Comment: It won't solve the issue

Comment: Any error messages??

Comment: There will be no error messages, but you can't see dialog .

Comment: Please test the issue before posting an answer. I don't like to down vote someone precious time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).